# How to concatenate, format and then split again strings in Yahoo Pipes

Tags: pipe, yahoo, yahoo-pipes

I am trying to fetch a feed and then add one field to every entry using Yahoo Pipes.

In order to get content of fields I'd like to add, I have to fetch some data from my server using Fetch Data (http://www.myserver.com/?get=author)

However I would like to get informations for all entries in just one request (http://www.myserver.com/?get=author1-author2-author3) instead of making as many requests as number of entries is.

My problem is that I can't figure out how to create string that would consist of all  fields with "-" delimiter (author1-author2-author3...). I tried experiment with Loop but with no success.

Moreover, I can't find a way to join fetched data with entries. Loop doesn't seem deliver such function.

My feed:

```
<item><author>author1</author></item>
<item><author>author2</author></item>
<item><author>author3</author></item>
```

What I want to achive:

```
<item><author>author1</author><authorid>34</authorid></item>
<item><author>author2</author><authorid>54</authorid></item>
<item><author>author3</author><authorid>30</authorid></item>
```

I don't expect a running Pipe, just a tip how can I do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a web server why use Yahoo Pipes to join the data? It would be easier to perform server side with PHP.

Alternatively..
You could use the *replace* module with regex and work on the feed as a string but that's probably going to be an ugly hackjob of a pipe. Would need the URL for the donor feed and your site to help further.